# How to stop document.ready from exection in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My query in the below code is --- I used a function slider in document.ready.Now my query is that when I click 'dot1' The function slider in the document.ready to stop execute until the function is called again. How to achieve this?Can anyone help me..... 
Thanking you in advance.
here is my code:

```
    var imgValue;
    var value;
    var flag;

    function ClickEvent() {
        $('span[id^="dot"]').click(function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            var Clickid = $(event.target)[0].id;
            $('.image1').css('display', 'none');
            $('.innerdiv').css('display', 'none');

            switch (Clickid) {
                case 'dot1':
                    {
                        debugger;
                        SliderTimer = null;
                        clearInterval(SliderTimer);
                        flag = 0;
                        value = 1;
                        ImageLoad(value);

                        //setTimeout(SlideImage(), 150000);
                        //alert("dot1 Clicked");                         
                        break;
                    }
                case 'dot2':
                    {
                        //alert("dot2 Clciked");
                        //setTimeout(SlideImage(), 5000);
                        value = 2;
                        ImageLoad(value);
                        //setTimeout(SlideImage(), 150000);
                        //alert("dot2 Clicked");
                        break;
                    }
                case 'dot3':
                    {
                        //alert("dot3 Clicked");
                        //setTimeout(SlideImage(), 5000);
                        value = 3;
                        ImageLoad(value);
                        //setTimeout(SlideImage(), 150000);
                        //alert("dot3 Clicked");
                        break;
                    }
            }
        });
    }

    function ImageLoad(count) {

        $('* span').css('background-color', '#ccc');
        $('.Dots #dot' + count).delay(4500).css('background-color', "Black");


        $('.image #img' + count).show('fade', { direction: 'right' }, 1000);

        $('.image #indiv' + count).delay(1500).show('fade', 1000);
        $('.image #indiv' + count).delay(2500).hide('fade', { direction: 'left' }, 1000);

        $('.image #img' + count).delay(4500).hide('fade', { direction: 'left' }, 1000);

    }

    function LoadPage() {
        $('.image #img1').show('fade', 1000);
        $('* span').css('background-color', '#ccc');
        $('.Dots #dot1').css('background-color', 'Black');
    }

    $(document).ready(function Slider() {

        var sc = $('.image img').size();

        LoadPage();
        value = 1;

        setInterval(SliderTimer, 5000);

        ClickEvent();

    });

    var SliderTimer = function SliderImage() {
        var sc = $('.image img').size();

        ImageLoad(value);

        if (value == sc) {
           value = 1;
        }
        else {
           value += 1;
        }            
    }
</script>
```

Comment: We could if you showed your code?

Comment: setInterval is pure javascript http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: yes Liam I hope u will help me

Comment: Easier to use `setTimeout` and have it re-trigger itself rather than using `setInterval`. It's a lot easier to control that way.

Answer (score 5):

Use [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearInterval) :

```
var timer = setInterval(function() { ... }, 666); 

...

$('#butt').click(function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
});
```

---

EDIT : here's how your code would look :

```
var sliderTimer;

function ClickEvent() {
   ...

        switch (Clickid) {
            case 'dot1':
                {
                    clearInterval(sliderTimer);

    ...
}

...

$(document).ready(function Slider() {
    ...
    sliderTimer = setInterval(SliderTimer, 5000);
    ClickEvent();
});

function SliderImage() {
    var sc = $('.image img').size();
    ImageLoad(value);
    if (value == sc) {
       value = 1;
    }
    else {
       value += 1;
    }            
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not working ? Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: @user2440327 SliderTimer = null; clearInterval(SliderTimer);   in your code. Purpose of this?

Comment: And the last `var SliderTimer = function SliderImage()...` is very weird too.